# Could not get instance id in ec2 console

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to get ec2 instance id and assign it into environment variable with a script.
I found some command that supposed to give me the id but they don't work.

The `curl` command returns nothing:
[curl command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gz4X.png),
I tried this way also: `` export INSTANCE_ID=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id ``, but the variable is empty.

The `cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_asset_tag` command prints the id, but when I try to assign it to the variable, I get Permission Denied error.

Any ideas why curl returns nothing, or any other way to get the instance id?
Thanks

Comment: You may have disabled support for metadata for your instance. You have to check that.

Comment: Which amazon ami you are using? Metadata is enabled or not? Does this command work `ec2-metadata -i`

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Yes, that command works! This is exactly what I needed. So what is this command?

Comment: If you don't mind, I would post my comment as an answer. Is it possible to accept it as answer so that it help others in the future

Answer (score 0):

If you have cloud-utils on your machine, you can try

```bash
INSTANCE_ID=$(ec2metadata --instance-id)
```

Comment: Ok I'm not familiar with cloud-utils but I'll explore it. Thanks!

Comment: On ubuntu / debian you can install it with

sudo apt update \
sudo apt install cloud-utils

Answer (score 0):

As per comment the problem was solved by using the ec2-metadata tool:

```
ec2-metadata -i
```

On the Amazon Linux AMI, there is a tool already pre-installed called ec2-metadata which can be run from the command line interface (CLI).

If it's something other than Amazon AMI then install it first and then use it:

```
# Download the ec2-metadata script
wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2metadata/ec2-metadata

# Modify the permission to execute the bash script
chmod +x ec2-metadata
```